# Asus laptop touchpad stopped working and looks disconnected

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, touchpad, peripherals

**The problem:**

I'm using an asus UX410U laptop under windows 10 for high school. Since few months,the touchpad it stopped working when it was heating too much, nothing too disabling for classes. Today, when I was working in class, it suddenly stopped working. I checked windows 10 settings and saw that the touchpad tab disappeared, after this, I checked the device manager and the touchpad was missing. Right now, after a restart it still don't work.

**Additional information:**

The laptop is 6 years old and was mostly used for text editors, retrogaming and a little bit of programming (gentle usage). However, it was daily transported with a backpack.
HJow can I solve this problem?

Comment: Repair is fairly simple, listed about US$60 at https://www.laptopinventory.com/Laptop_Model.php/Asus/ZenBook/UX410U/TP, but I'd just get an inexpensive mouse, which I find more precise and flexible than a touchpad. Also check for a loose connector, likely in a laptop frequently transported.

Comment: Battery could also be swollen - get the repair shop to look at that too.

Comment: Reinstall the touchpad software, I had an ethernet controller disappear from device manager, reinstall the driver and now it works and now shows in device manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, it was a driver issue solved by reinstalling it. You can download the exact one driver [here](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/DriversForWin10/TouchPad/Touchpad_ASUS_Win10_64_VER110030_DriverOnly.zip).

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by a faulty ribbon cable, try to open your laptop and see if you can get to the touchpad (be careful as you can break alot of things in the process).

Once there, try to disconnect and reconnect the ribbon cable. If it does not work then buy a identical ribbon cable (the number of pins at both ends of the cable matters).

If the new cable don't work then only should you buy and replace the touchpad itself.

This can save you quite a nice amount of money if it's just a faulty ribbon cable since the cable itself cost afew dollars whereas the touchpad is much more expensive.

Comment: Never seen a laptop ribbon cable go bad unless someone worked on it.

Comment: Owh is that so, that would explain my situation XD. Thanks for the new info !